DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE issue for subdomains with Traefik
I have a server running some services through Traefik.
Since mingling with my mail server and Traefik setup yesterday, some services / subdomains have DNS issues now (DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE or DNS_..._NXDOMAIN; regardless of ISP, Client or Browser). When accessing those subdomains, traefik does not even log a request and states no errors anything (i guess this means it does not even receive the request). The services and corresponding routing rules are recognized by Traefik as I can see them in the Traefik dashboard.
Things I have tried so far:

restarting all containers and pruning docker networks
restarting server
use a different DNS on the client side, different client, different ISP
explicitly add a DNS A entry for the subdomain

I have no ideas where to look for the problem/solution, most internet threads say it is a client side issue, but that's not possible since it is happening regardless of the client.

When accessing those subdomains, traefik does not even log a request and states no errors anything - Looks like you have issue in DNS entry. Check are those subdomains pointing to traefik's IP?

I already did: - explicitly add a DNS A entry for the subdomain

Then what is output of dig? Does it reach to Traefik?
